# How to call save method in mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument class

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

```
import mongoengine

class Model1(mongoengine.DynamicDocument):
    name = mongoengine.StringField()
    addr = mongoengine.EmbeddedDocumentField(Model2)

class Model2(mongoengine.EmbeddedDocument):
    loc =  mongoengine.StringField()
    # do some stuff
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "test line print...."
        super(Model2, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

now when I save `Model1` instance. it doesn't call save method

```
m2 = Model2(loc='some text')
m1 = Model1(name='name')
m1.addr = m2
m1.save()
```

if I try to explicity call the save method on Model2, it complains that `NoneType object has no attr save`

Answer (score 0):

`m2` (embedded doc) does have a `save` method. It calls `m1.save()`. See [the code](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/blob/7748e68440df2e3ad2d48ec0b55b9647c4de014d/mongoengine/document.py#L49).

The assumption *calling m1.save() will call save() on all embedded documents* is false. (I fell in the same trap...)

So unfortunately, you can't safely override an embedded document's save method expecting it to be called each time the document is saved.

But you can add it a `pre_save` method you call from `m1.save()` (or in a callback catching the `pre_save` [signal](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/signals.html?highlight=signals) in the document).

However, calling `m2.save()` should call `m1.save()` and save the whole document. I can't explain this error: `NoneType object has no attr save`. You should edit your question to provide the full traceback.